# Torquemeter without Changing the Power Output of a Motor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, torque

Is there any way to measure the torque of an engine without reducing the power output of a motor? A ton of dynamometer seem to apply a load on the engine, which works well for static tests, but how can the torque be measured on a running car or boat without affecting the output too much?

Comment: do you want to measure the torque or the power? Both can be demanding to perform dynamically,  To my knowledge most of the measurements are done in laboratory environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a force measurement gauge  (a *load cell*) that measures the load imposed on the vehicle's engine mounts by the engine as it is running. Knowing the distance from the engine centerline to the engine mount, you can calculate the torque being transmitted. Knowing the RPM, you now know the instantaneous power output of the engine.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

"Torque" infers a force against something.  To determine what the torque is, it needs to push against that something, and you need a way to measure that force.

Since you say automotive, I'll assume you mean an internal combustion engine as mounted in a vehicle.  Engine torque (and thus power) were meaured traditionally by spinning something against a brake and measuring the resulting force of th ebrake's bracket, or these days spinning up a cylinder and measuring the rate of change of its RPM versus its rotational inertia.  These are done at wide open throttle, not many people really care about the torque at 10% throttle besides I guess the manufacturer.

No, there isn't really a way to determine the torque of a car in motion except by measuring its acceleration and thus the force to accelerate it.  But you don't know the power required to move the car through the air, which you wouldn't measure.  The torque required to hold a car at a steady speed might be able to be determined in a wind tunnel with the right force measurements of the car's mount, back-calculated to the engine.

In-line torque transducers are a thing, and are used in industrial electric motors.  Certainly nothing you can do to your own vehicle easily without modifying the drive train.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking a dynamometer for a torque transducer. A dynamometer's expressed purpose is to apply a know load to an engine and measure the resulting speed and torque so that you can characterize the engine. To that end, a dynamometer will include a torque transducer.

Most torque transducers are constructed as device that sits in between two shafts. They work as rotary strain gages that measure the twist between two ends of a shaft.

But as you probably guessed from my description, they are very invasive. You would literally need to find a piece of shaft somewhere and insert the torque transducer there.

EDIT:

I suppose in theory you could adhere an appropriate strain gauge  to the outside of the shaft with wireless transmission circuitry, and stick everything on a dynamometer to calibrate the strain gauge before sending it onto the road.

Answer (score 0):

If the motor is driving something via a conrod, you could try a strain gauge on the surface of the conrod, oriented to measure axial strain.  If you know the Young's modulus and cross-sectional area of the conrod, you can covert axial strain to axial load, then the product of axial load in the conrod with distance from the axis of the motor to the point of attachment of the conrod is the torque.